# Conditional header appearance based on chapter name

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, ifthenelse

I am converting a complex markdown document to pdf using pandoc. And need to add some formatting to it during the conversion. So I cannot have the styling and the data at the same place, means, I cannot do a target style assignment with something like `\thispagestyle`. How can I make a general conditional headers\footers for some pages?
What I can think of now for removing header on the pages with table of content is below. It is not working for some reason.
(for this case `\fancyhead[C]{\textsl{\leftmark}}` would set the word 'CONTENTS' in the header of this page).

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pagestyle{fancy}
... 
some general header/footer style 
...
\fancyheadinit{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{Contents} \OR \equal{\leftmark}{CONTENTS}}
        {
          \fancyhf{}
          {\fancyhead[C]{\textsl{\rightmark}}}
          \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        }
}
```

Comment: `\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{toc}\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{normal}` where `toc` and `normal` have suitable definitions with `\fancypagestyle`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thought process for a solution:

1. Capture the chapter name/title in something like `\chaptername` by redefining `\chapter`.
2. Look up with the chapter name of the ToC actually looks like in the class you use (I've looked at [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co) which are both the same; it may be different for other document classes). Store that in `\ToCchaptername`.
3. Compare the current `\chaptername` against `\ToCchaptername` to condition on what you (don't) set.

The following example does that, leaving the ToC without any heading at all.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

% Capture the chapter name/title in \chaptername
\makeatletter
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{#3}\def\chaptername{#3}}% \chapter*{...}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}\def\chaptername{#2}}% \chapter[..]{...}
      {\oldchapter{#3}\def\chaptername{#3}}}% \chapter{...}
  \markright{}% Clear possible section mark left by ToC
}
% Taken from https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co
\def\ToCchaptername{\contentsname \@mkboth{%
  \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
\makeatother
  
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadinit{%
  \fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  % Compare chapter title/name to that of ToC
  \ifx\chaptername\ToCchaptername
    % What to do when you're in the ToC
  \else
    % What to do when you're not in the ToC
    \fancyhead[C]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{First section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{Final section}\lipsum[41-50]

\end{document}
```

A small edge-case had to be considered (because you're setting `\rightmark`) since the ToC sets *both* left/right header to be `\contentsname`. So, if the first chapter after the ToC has a long introduction (spilling onto a second page) before the first `\section` (and therefore `\rightmark`) is set, you could be in a new chapter and set the word `\contentsline` as part of `\rightmark`. As such, we clear the `\rightmark` when we call `\chapter` (via `\markright{}`).